# Converting Bitwise Statements in C to Delphi

Tags: c++, c, delphi

The following statements in C:

```
iONE >>= iShift;
iONE &= 0xffefffff;
iONE |= (((((long)(*temp & 0x7f) - 65) << 2) + iShift + 1023) << 20) | (iTWO & 0x80000000);
```

Is there something like `shr=`, `And=` and `Or=` in Delphi.  Is there more appropriate way than literal porting, especially the third statement.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you read a Delphi (or even Pascal) tutorial or reference?

Comment: I did a search online and not finding the answer, yet. I do not have Embarcadero Delphi but plan to purchase Delphi XE8.

Comment: Why don't you read some documentation? For instance: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B and http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Expressions_(Delphi)

Comment: Thank you. Very useful. Somehow I missed it when searching.

Comment: Thank you to all the experts.  I updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are basically two operations combined.
`x >>= y` means `x = x >> y`.
The same applies for `&=` and `|=`.
And for the Delphi part: [And](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=And), [Or](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=Or), and [Right Shift](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=Shr).

Comment: Thank you. That is what I thought, but do not want to second guessing.

Comment: You don't need to guess. Both of these languages have a lot of comprehensive publicly available documentation. You'll gain confidence by finding that documentation and reading it.